# Keras/Tensorflow - Custom loss function is equal to 0 when run_eagerly=None?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss-function

```
custom_loss_layer = CustomLossLayer(params)(inputs, outputs)

model.add_loss(custom_loss_layer)

model.compile(..., loss="categorical_crossentropy", run_eagerly=True)
```

Running .evaluate() on model with run_eagerly=True, I get a loss of 10- higher than the combined losses of all outputs, as should be expected. However, run_eagerly brings with it a lot of performance problems. If I set run_eagerly to None instead and run .evaluate() again, the loss is only around 3, exactly equal to the combined losses of all outputs. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

I suspect that the nature of the loss function/layer might have something to do with it- In one step, the inputs are converted from one-hot encoded to scalar values via tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(input)), which is then converted to an simple integer used to access list indices. I suspect that since this step reduces a tensor to a primitive value, tensorflow is unable to track how the tensor is modified in a single execution of the model which messes up preprocessing steps that bring the performance benefits of disabling run_eagerly. For the record, the loss function works fine with run_eagerly enabled as printing shows, and is correctly minimised after a few epochs to only 2 or so (neglecting losses from categorical crossentropy)

Loss function:

```
class IntervalPenaltyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, intelligible_intervals, pitch_mapping, **kwargs):
    self._intelligible_intervals = intelligible_intervals
    self._pitch_mapping = pitch_mapping
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def call(self, inputs, outputs):
    factor = 5
    loss = 0

    input_current_tone_batch = inputs["tone_0"][:, -1, :]
    batch_size = input_current_tone_batch.shape[0]
    if batch_size is None:  # Check if it is still compiling
        return 0

    input_next_tone_batch = inputs["tone_1"][:, -1, :]
    input_pitch_batch = inputs["pitch"][:, -1, :]
    output_pitch_batch = outputs["pitch"]  # Output no need

    for i in range(batch_size):
        current_tone_tensor = input_current_tone_batch[i, :]
        next_tone_tensor = input_next_tone_batch[i, :]
        current_pitch_tensor = input_pitch_batch[i, :]
        predicted_pitch_tensor = output_pitch_batch[i, :]

        current_tone_idx = int(tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(current_tone_tensor, axis=-1)))
        next_tone_idx = int(tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(next_tone_tensor, axis=-1)))
        current_pitch_idx = int(tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(current_pitch_tensor, axis=-1)))

        current_pitch = self._pitch_mapping[current_pitch_idx]

        key = str(current_tone_idx) + "_" + str(next_tone_idx)
        if key not in self._intelligible_intervals:  # Rest or whatever, skipping
            continue

        possible_intervals = self._intelligible_intervals[key]

        for j in tf.range(tf.shape(predicted_pitch_tensor)[0]):
            new_pitch = self._pitch_mapping[int(j)]
            interval = new_pitch - current_pitch
            probability = tf.gather(predicted_pitch_tensor, j)
            if interval not in possible_intervals:
                loss += factor * probability

    return math.log(1 + loss)
```

Comment: This is completely impossible to answer without showing the custom loss.

Comment: Edited, added the custom loss function